# how to set a dynamic hash key (hash data type) in Redis & Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Trying to set a hash data type, that contains a dynamic key name.   I have a attribute for example called "event_id" which contains an integer.   I'd like that to be apart of the hash key name.

```
         self.attributes.each do |field, value|
          $redis.hset(event_id, field, value)
          end
         end
```

With the current code above,  the key in redis is looking like

```
        32434
```

The goal is that I can add some text in front of that key,  so that ideally the key would look like

```
        this:is:the:event_id:32434
```

I can't fiqure out the syntax in the key args without breaking the syntax.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiqured this out by creating a "redis namespace".  Then instead of doing $redis, which is the general namespace, I will call on this new namespace for the correct key name I'm after. The namespaces are nice way to organize your redis data.

```
          $redis_event   = Redis::Namespace.new("offer:with:event_id:", :redis => r)
```